# 2 SSMS installed, how to uninstall one?

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

I have installed SSMS 18.4. In the Control Panel I see only this SSMS. But when I enter SQL Server Management studio in the Windows Search field 2 studios appear:
SSMS 18
SSMS 16

and if I click SSMS 16 it runs.

How to uninstall an elder SSMS 16?

Comment: Like any other application. Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> {Application} -> Uninstall. You can use the Search bar (in the top right) to find the installs (try ["Management Studio"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCSP7.png))

Comment: Yes, it is in normal case. But I see the SSMS 18.4 Only in the CP. No any other SSMS

Comment: It'll be there, Oleg. use the search bar to find it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try and find the cached package file, which'll be somewhere in a subdirectory in `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` and the file should start with the name "SSMS-Setup", just make sure you run the correct one.